# Azure VM Managed Disks Drive letters

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-networking

I have a VM which has Windows OS Disk + More Managed Data Disks attached to it. Another azure VM has similar structure. I am trying to Automate Assign Drive Letter in another VM.

I checked Get-Disk, Get-Volume, Get-PSDrive, Get-Partition commands. I do not know how many partitions each source managed disk have, which partition of LUN is D: or E: etc etc. The targeted VM should have same Drive Letter assigned to same LUN and same Partitions.

No Resources are shared between Source and Target VM, All drive letters should be same as it is in source VM